# regex replace all matches based on pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
var testString = 'Please use "command1" to accept and "command2" to ignore';
```

All I'm trying to achive is replacing the string between the quotes but when replacing, I need to know what was inside the quotes.

After replacing it should be like:

```
var result = 'Please use <a href="someurl?cmd=command1">command1</a> to accept and <a href="someurl?cmd=command2">command2</a> to ignore';
```

I tried somethiing like this with no success:

```
            var rePattern = /\"(.*?)\"/gi;
            Text.replace(rePattern, function (match, txt, urlId) {
                return "rendered link for " + match;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `/"(.+?)"/g` to match all quoted text, with a capture group for the command without the quotes. Then you can use `"$1"` in the replacement string.

```js
'Please use "command1" to accept and "command2" to ignore'
.replace(/"(.+?)"/g, '<a href="someurl?cmd=$1">$1</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out MDN's documentation on `String.prototype.replace()`, specifically the section about [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```js
var testString = 'Please use "command1" to accept and "command2" to ignore';
var reg = /"([^"]+)"/g;
var testResult = testString.replace(reg, function (match, p1) {
    return '<a href="someurl?cmd=' + p1 + '">' + p1 + '</a>';
});
```

The first parameter to `replace` is the regular expression, and the second parameter is an anonymous function. That function is sent four arguments (see MDN's documentation), but we're only using the first two: `match` is the entire matched string -- either `"command1"` or `"command2"` -- and `p1` is the content of the first capture group in the regular expression, either `command1` or `command2` (without quotes). The string returned by this anonymous function is what those matches are replaced with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group and then reference it in a replace.

Find

```
/\"([^\"]+)\"/gm
```

Then replace

```
<a href="someurl?cmd=$1">$1</a>
```

https://regex101.com/r/kG3iL4/1

```
var re = /\"([^\"]+)\"/gm; 
var str = 'Please use "command1" to accept and "command2" to ignore';
var subst = '<a href="someurl?cmd=$1">$1</a>'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```